# How to receive plain Text through Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I was trying to send plain text through `Socket`. So I found a post in StackOverflow, I followed it and I guess it that I did it write However, How can I accept that plain text as string in the client? 
I used `BufferedReader()` and `InputStreamReader()` class, but exception has been thrown.

```
Exception : exception java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

Here is the code:
Server:

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
osw.write(fileName, 0, fileName.length());
```

Client:

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String fileName = br.readLine();
br.close();
```

Some help would be great. :) Thank you.

Client side code:

```
public void soc_client() throws Exception {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalRecieved = 0;

    try {
        Socket sock = new Socket("172.16.27.106", 55000);
        System.out.println("Hello Client");
        InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String fileName = br.readLine();
        File outputFile = new File(fileName + "");
        br.close(); // CLOSING BufferedReader

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalRecieved += bytesRead;
            System.out.println("Recieved " + (totalRecieved / 1024)
                    + " kilobytes in "
                    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) / 1000)
                    + " seconds");
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
        sock.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Recieved " + totalRecieved + " bytes in "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms.");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: exception java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
Sent 0 kilobytes in 21 seconds

Comment: post the code relevant to opening the socket

Comment: Yes - the exception should point to a particular line of code.

Comment: i caught the exception. it printed the exception from catch block

Comment: yes obviously... I wanted to know what the exception said...

Comment: Exception : exception java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading a line but you aren't sending a line, and you aren't closing the `OutputWriter` either. So `readLine()` will block forever waiting for a line terminator or an EOS that is never coming.

1. Add a newline to the message.
2. Close the `OutputWriter.`

Comment: How can I do so? Sorry. I am novice.

Comment: I managed to send the filename as String through Socket. 
My Code was: PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
pw.print(fileName);

However, the file came empty this time! Should I post the code?

Comment: What part of "add a newline to the message" and "close the `OutputWriter`" don't you understand?

Comment: got it. I fixed that problem. :) Thank you. I am now receiving the text perfectly but I am getting the error Broken Pipe. Sorry i did not post it in here.

should I open a new post or post my current code here for the broken pipe error? I closed all the connection inside finally in client and server both.

Answer (score -1):

Well to use sockets to send and transfer text in client server fashion , i'm posting a simple basic code , which upon running send a HELLO WORLD response to client.

//Server Side

```
ServerSocket server= new ServerSocket(1166); // //1166 -port no. u can use any other too.
Socket  s= server.accept(); // makes a connection whenever a client requests.

OutputStream os= socket.getOutputStream();

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

dos.writeUTF("Hello World");

dos.close();
```

// Client Side

```
Socket socket= new Socket("Ip address of you server" , 1166) ;
InputStream is= new InputStream();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

String msg=dis.readUTF();
System.out.println(msg);
dis.close();
```

now after you run the code once on server computer , then run the client side code and the server will now respond you with Hello World.